# Redshift unloading to S3 using unload command, is the overwrite operation on S3 object atomic?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Let's say if we run the unload command with
`parallel off` and `allowoverwrite` so we have only one file in its output.

If some other reader tries to read the same object while unload command is running, can they see any inconsistent state in between ?

`allowoverwrite` I think does delete first and then put .

While put operation is atomic on S3, is overwrite via unload atomic ? Can there be a state in between where the reader might get no file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issues here.  "Parallel off" does not ensure that only 1 file will be written.  Redshift will create new files when the max file size is reached - 5GB by default.  If you know you will never exceed this size then 1 file will be created.

As for delete before write, I don't believe Redshift does anything like this but I don't think it is guaranteed.  It would be inefficient to do this so why would they but you are relying on an unsupported attribute.

A better approach would be unload to a different location and then move the file to the desired location using S3 API calls.  This does use documented and supported behaviors.  What you are trying to do "should work" (if the file is small enough) but if it fails you will get no support or changes changes in AWS services to correct.